# Atheist Jew, but keeping the most basic Torah laws, what will wait him in the afterlife?

Tags: halacha, afterlife

I am asking about a Jew. He is 100% materialist, atheist in his world view.

He keeps the most basic laws of Judaism: keeps Sabbath (not so strictly as Orthodox Jews do, but keeps), doesn't eat pork and doesn't mix milk and meat. (I don't know if he has brith, but I am nearly sure, that he has.) Not every weekend, but he is a regular visitor in a local synagogue.

I think, he does it because although he doesn't believe the religion, he wants to honor his religious friends and ancestors. Furthermore, this is the way of life he is accustomed to.

I think it would be nicer if he would do what God wants from him. But, somewhere I've read, that Judaism is more like law as simply a religion. And he keeps the law on a basic level.

So, what will happen to a Jew, keeping basic laws, but not believing anything over the pure matter?

Comment: you sure he doesnt believe deep down?

Comment: Your case is perhaps a case of a man who like to say that he doesn't believe and to act that he believe.

Comment: @ray It can be hard to say even from ourself. I am sure he is non-believer on conscient level.

Answer (score 1):

One who does not believe in the principles of Judaism does not merit the World to Come. This is stated clearly at the beginning of the [chapter of Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90a?lang=bi) that discusses the topic:

> כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעולם הבא שנאמר (ישעיהו ס, כא) ועמך כולם צדיקים לעולם יירשו ארץ נצר מטעי מעשה ידי להתפאר ואלו שאין להם חלק לעולם הבא האומר אין תחיית המתים מן התורה ואין תורה מן השמים ואפיקורוס
> MISHNA: All of the Jewish people, even sinners and those who are liable to be executed with a court-imposed death penalty, have a share in the World-to-Come, as it is stated: “And your people also shall be all righteous, they shall inherit the land forever; the branch of My planting, the work of My hands, for My name to be glorified” (Isaiah 60:21). And these are the exceptions, the people who have no share in the World-to-Come, even when they fulfilled many mitzvot: One who says: There is no resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah, and one who says: The Torah did not originate from Heaven, and an epikoros, who treats Torah scholars and the Torah that they teach with contempt.

The idea that Judaism is merely a religion of laws without concern for belief is a common misconception. As far as I can tell is that it comes from the Christian perspective that Judaism is a dry religion of laws and rote practice, which they believe Jesus replaced with a focus on belief. This is convenient and lazy caricature they use to explain why Christianity replaced Judaism.

The truth is that Judaism is an all-encompassing religion, that deals with the physical, the mental, and the spiritual aspect of people, as the author of the classic work [Duties of the Heart](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Introduction_of_the_Author?lang=en) explains in his introduction.

Comment: While there was definitely a later push throughout Prophets (long before Christianity) to keep the law with sincerity and mind the spirit of the law, and an even later introduction of fundamental beliefs such as Maimonides' 13 principals that everyone was expected to have, Judaism is most concerned with actions and keeping the letter of the law. That is not a misconception.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this source specifies one "saying" these heretical beliefs, not just thinking or believing them. As long as you keep these beliefs to yourself, and don't "say" them, spreading them to others, it seems like you would be ok, even according to this.

Comment: @BabySeal It is absolutely a misconception. The book of Deuteronomy as a whole is concerned with proper beliefs. As for the Mishnah using the term "saying", in the entire Talmud that term is used to refer to what a person's opinion is, not necessarily what they said.

Comment: "As far as I can tell is that it comes from the Christian perspective that Judaism is a dry religion of laws and rote practice" I think you mean 'Protestant' (circa 500 years ago) not Christian. No Christians preached this strawman of Judaism before the Protestants. The New Testament is clear that all the Jews who were saved, like the patriarchs, who were saved by their heroic deeds, and their keeping of the law, were saved, ultimately, by their steadfast devotion (faith) in the God who gave the commandmenst and laws. They didn't just follow laws without moral concern (e.g. who gave the laws).

Comment: @SolaGratia As a Jew, my main concern is that this idea is not Jewish, but a non-Jewish caricature. Whether it was all Christians or just some is not particularly relevant to me.

Comment: I don't think you would be expected to consider it fair if one were to lump all Jews in with every sect of Judaism, such as the Karaites who completely reject any oral torah, which obviously isn't "the" Jewish perspective by a long shot. But whatever.

Comment: @SolaGratia You may be right, and I hope I did not offend you or anyone else.

Comment: Not at all, no offense taken.

Comment: @BabySeal https://seforimblog.com/2021/04/response-to-criticism-part-4-rabbi-zvi-yehuda-and-the-hazon-ish/ Not saying it aloud may arguably prevent you from having the social ramifications of a heretic (invalid as a witness, etc.) but it won't help you in the afterlife.

Comment: Can you define "principles of Judaism" that existed before Maimonides (attempted to) codify them? One of the reasons rambam codified them was because he saw that there was no such quorum at large. So no one had a share in the world to come before him? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: The Mishna I quoted codifies the main ones: techiyas hameisim, accepting the Torah is from G-d (implying a more fundamental need to believe in G-d and prophecy), which then means accepting the principles stated in the Torah, such as the Torah not changing, reward and punishment, etc. The Rambam codified them as part of his commentary on the Mishnah; any other "reasons" are pure speculation. Saadya Gaon and Chovos Halevavos wrote extensively on required beliefs; the only difference is they devoted entire books to the topic, instead of a short list as part of a commentary on a mishnah.

Answer (score 0):

From the TaNaKH and from the Talmud, we read about these two ultimate "afterlife"-destinations, inclusive of a time-frame:

> "And many of them that sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake,
>   some to everlasting life, and some to reproaches and everlasting
>   abhorrence."
>
> ([Daniel 12:2](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm))

Death is like sleep. Just as we wake-up from sleep, we also wake-up from death.

> Yochanan Ben-Zakkai said, "I have two paths before me, one of the
>   Garden of Eden and one of Gehenna, and I do not know on which they are
>   leading me;"
>
> ([www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.28b))

Dying is like walking, a continuous process of being, and therefore "after death" (upon the continuous process of being), we encounter a fork on the road, one fork leads to Gan-Eden, and the other to Gehenna.

> Master of the Universe, You have judged properly, You have acquitted
>   properly, You have condemned properly, and it is befitting that You
>   have prepared Gehenna for the wicked and the Garden of Eden for the
>   righteous.
>
> ([www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a))

This quote, from the Talmud, tells us the courtroom time-frame after death or "afterlife", there is judgment ("You have judged properly"), which either leads to acquittal ("You have acquitted properly") or condemnation ("You have condemned properly"). A sentence of condemnation condemns one into the hellish "Gehenna"-Destination, whereas an acquittal leads into the heavenly "Garden of Eden"-Destination.

Thus is the "afterlife" nature, according to Orthodox Judaism as fleshed-out in both the above sources from the TaNaKH and Talmud.

Comment: In a short answer, G-d never judges a person for what they didn't know. — Sourced somewhere.

Comment: @TurkHill source please.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to find the source as I read it many decades ago somewhere. Be this as it may, the idea is certainly correct.

Comment: @TurkHill I am not sure that "G-d never judges a person for what they didn't know", because in everyday life, that is not even true. If one truly believes that such and such action is not illegal (and it is) and one committed such an action, the Law will not excuse such a person.

Comment: Although I agree that there is no excuse when you are aware of the law, you will admit that Judaism is unlike Christianity which sends people to hell simply because they never heard of a man named Jesus. I don’t like that kind of religion (Judaism) because it sounds good. No. It’s the truth. And the truth is the truth no matter what’s its source - Maimonides

Comment: @TurkHill the answer that I quoted above is in the Gemara. Yochanan Ben-Zakkai gives the possibility that he could receive a judgment that he does not want or expect. How do you react to that?

Comment: I am a maimonidean, a rationalist. Maimonides said that some rabbis are not always correct because they did not always understood the laws of nature.

Comment: @TurkHill Did Maimonides give a criteria how one can recognize "rabbis" who "are not always correct"? Please source it.

Comment: Here is an example. There was once a black king who had a white son. When he asked the Rebbe why his son was white, the Rebbe pointed to the white portraits. Today we know it is genetics. But Maimonides wrote that the rabbis were not experts in science and only understood what was presented to them at that time. Guide to the Perplexed, III:14

Comment: @TurkHill just so we are clear, ending up in Gan-Eden  or Gehenna has nothing to do with science.

Comment: Let’s define some terms. You write, “Yochanan Ben-Zakkai gives the possibility.” So this is not even a fact. Just a possibility. 2nd, the soul has already been proven by science. Physicists say that energies travel around after death. This, some think is the soul. Not to mention that these discoveries were made by secular people. Maimonides often spoke of the active intellect which reflects modern discovery. By deduction, if the soul exist, so does Gan-Eden & Gehenna. However, the Torah is silent on the afterlife and reincarnation mysticism do not exist.

Comment: To be clear, getting to Gan-Eden has everything to do with science. Maimonides wrote in his guide that G-d was formless in a time when most Jews believed G-d looked like a man! The reason he wrote this was because only by doing mitzvots and having correct knowledge about G-d can one rejoice. So he wrote the first half of the 13 principles correctly about the nature of G-d and the rest to please the masses who believed that the sun literally stopped for Joshua.

Comment: By giving them the truth about G-d, they were not idolatrous. How does one know about the laws of nature and G-d? Through Torah and science. Maimonides was a big advocate for science and would probably accept theory of evolution.

Comment: Maimonides was not just a rabbi but he was also a physician to the Sultan of Egypt. This illustrates that he was a philosopher. A rationalist. And certainly not a mystic.

Comment: @TurkHill “Yochanan Ben-Zakkai gives the possibility” because he did not know which of the two places he would end up. So you know? In regards to Maimonides, how do you know Maimonides is not mistaken in any of his beliefs, esp. the afterlife?

Comment: You doubt Maimonides? Of course he’s not mistaken. Science has proven his theory of the afterlife more than any other. In regards to your first question, G-d knows best. He is a just G-d and judges people by what they knew. See R. Singer

Comment: @TurkHill I don't doubt Maimonides, but you are convincing me to doubt Rabbi Yochanan Ben-Zakkai of the Mishna?

Comment: No. But while R. Zakkai May be mistaken on one point does not mean he is in another. He is right to assume that it is impossible to know and that one may be surprised where they go. My point is that a good atheist should not be judged on something he doesn’t know. As referenced in this question.

Comment: @TurkHill "... a good atheist should not be judged on something he doesn’t know." I responded to this already. If human judges do not agree with this reasoning (i.e. a person can not use ignorance of human law to get off the hook), what makes you think our heavenly judge would?

Comment: The difference lies in the judge. In our earthly court, anyone could claim innocence by ignorance. There’s no way of knowing. But in the heavenly court, G-d knows who lies and tells the truth. The truth is the truth no matter what’s its source— Maimonides

Comment: This answer states that there is judgement. But does it answer *what* the judgement is going to be? An atheist doesn't go and start worshipping another god. An atheist doesn't break the commandments that relate to human interactions (מצוות שבין אדם לחברו), at least no more than a religious person does. The Prophets consider those to be more important than those that have to do with relationship between man and God (מצוות שבין האדם למקום). So how is that put in the balance?

Comment: @Galastel "But does it answer what the judgement is going to be?" The answer in context: "Gehenna".

Comment: Where does it say the judgement is going to be Gehenna?

Comment: @Galastel 'Yochanan Ben-Zakkai said, "I have two paths before me, one of the Garden of Eden and one of Gehenna, and I do not know on which they are leading me;" (www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.28b)'

Comment: Very well - there are two paths. Where does it say that being a decent person and not worshipping other gods isn't enough to keep you on the path to heaven?

Comment: @Galastel can you deduce an answer from the reaction and statement of Yochanan Ben-Zakkai?

Comment: He says "I do not know on which they are leading me". Meaning maybe yes, maybe no. I see no reason to assume Gehenna.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -5):

G-d says, “if only Me they would abandon but My Torah they would observe.” This means that an atheist Jew who keeps Torah is a Jew in good standing in the eyes of G-d.

Comment: Is there a reason you needed to add a second terrible answer? What (wrong information) is this adding that wasn't in the first (terrible) answer?

Comment: @Salmononius2 The second was more condensed and more to the point (precise). If you think it's so terrible, feel free to state why and debunk it.

Comment: @Salmononius2 G-d says, “if only Me they would abandon but My Torah they would observe.” Idk how you could say otherwise. Do you disagree with G-d?

Comment: (1) Where does G-d say this? (2) How do you deduce from the statement that it means to include atheist Jews? Maybe it's only talking about idolatrous Jews. (3) How do you deduce from the statement that an atheist Jew who keeps Torah is a Jew _in good standing_ in the eyes of G-d? Maybe it's saying that abandoning G-d while still observing His Torah is just a lesser evil.

Comment: @TamirEvan I suppose your right that Jews who abandon G-d while observing Torah is a lesser evil. It is a Midrash, and it seems to be talking about atheistic Jews since it refers to Jews who abandon G-d but keep the Torah out of observance.

Comment: Please remove one of your duplicate answers.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I don't know how to do it. How do you do it?

Comment: @Deuteronomy I removed one of the answers.

Comment: “if only Me they would abandon but My Torah they would observe.” - as pointed out in this comments. Where in the Torah is this stated? As far as I know, there is no such thing stated.

Comment: @mvs Not the Torah, it's a Midrash. See midrash Eicha Rabbah Petichta 2. It says G-d prefer you be an atheist if you observe his Torah.

Comment: @TamirEvan See midrash Eicha Rabbah Petichta 2.

Comment: @TurkHill Found it, thanks! However, interesting that you connect this Midrash to an atheist....

Comment: It says, “if only Me they would abandon (atheism) but My Torah they would observe.”

Comment: @TurkHill If that's the _midrash_ you're quoting, then you're quoting only part of it, and mistranslating it at that. First, the mistranslation: The text says "הלואי אותי עזבו ותורתי שמרו". A better translation would have been: "if only Me they **had** abandon**ed** but My Torah they **had** observe**d**". The statement is about actions they should have done _in the past_. ...

Comment: @TurkHill ...  Second, the context: The verse the _midrash_ is commenting on says: "_say to them, 'Because your fathers deserted Me—declares the LORD—and **followed other gods** and served them and worshiped them; they deserted Me and did not keep My Instruction.'_". Abandoning G-d [in this _midrash_] _was_ in following other gods. ...

Comment: @TurkHill ...  Third, even if one would concede that the statement was to include atheist Jews, the last part of what "G-d says" is: "... _As they busied themselves with it, the illumination within it **would have brought them back to goodness**_". That would mean that they would have improved their chances to do _teshuvah_, and not be immediately punished, but _not_ that they would _automatically_ be Jew in good standing, or have a share in the World to Come (as the OP seems to be asking about).

Comment: @TamirEvan The Midrash contains two parts. First G-d declares that it would be better to abandon G-d but to observe the Torah. (ie good deeds is more important than faith). The "good" here refers to moral and not in the ritual sense, for if a person is an atheist it is likely that they don't observe rituals. This is pragmatic; the essence of Judaism is good deeds. But faith in G-d is the essence of a religious life. For, by observing Torah, they may return to faith in G-d.

Comment: @TamirEvan The situation is not ideal in the first place by them being an atheist. First, the Midrash states a point of fact then what is ideal. Ideally, the midrash holds the second part, that faith in G-d is important. However, the pragmatic nature of the midrash is tolerant and can accept the unfortunate and actual situation where one is choosing between faith or good deeds and picks the latter, but that the study and observance of Torah will ultimately lead to the ideal of faith in G-d, the essence of Judaism.

Comment: @TamirEvan The Midrash allows for tolerance and optimism in that through study and observance of Torah such a person will ultimately come to faith in G-d.

Comment: @TurkHill "_First G-d declares that it would be better to abandon G-d but to observe the Torah_" **Wrong!** G-d declares that it would **have** be**en** better if **they had** abandon**ed** G-d but **had** observe**d** His Torah ("הלואי אותי עזב**ו** ותורתי שמר**ו**"). "They" G-d spoke of, were "_your fathers_ [who] _deserted Me_ ... _**and followed other gods** and served them and worshiped them; **they** deserted Me and did not keep My Instruction_" (as [the verse states](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.16.11?lang=bi&with=Eichah%20Rabbah&lang2=en)). Where do atheists come in??

Comment: @TamirEvan The Talmudic rabbis were not historians. The midrash cited Jeremiah not because they were concerned with history. They were teachers of Torah (instruction), moral and spiritual guidance not only to Jews living in the Talmudic period but to future generations as well. It refers to future generations and it refers to anyone who denies G-d.

Comment: @TamirEvan What is wrong?

Comment: @TamirEvan Your missing the point. The rabbis weren't historians. They weren't concerned with history. Rabbi means teacher. They taught morals and guidance to Jews. It does refer to future generations. It refers to anyone who denies G-d.

Comment: @TamirEvan Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135477/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-tamir-evan).

Comment: איכה רבתי פתיחה ב      ר' הונא ור' ירמיה בשם ר' חייא בר אבא אמרי: כתיב: (ירמיהו טז יא): "ואותי עזבו ואת תורתי לא שמרו". הלואי אותי עזבו ותורתי שמרו, מתוך שהיו מתעסקין בה, המאור שבה היה מחזירן למוטב.

Comment: @TamirEvan I did not reply to you because I was sick with Covid. Abandoning G-d certainly does mean to deny G-d. Why would you think otherwise? Unless you want to reject the plain meaning of the midrash?  "If only Me they would abandon..." does not translate as deny - it means deny. If one abandons G-d, then this means that one denies G-d. Also Rambam's law code was composed for the masses and does not reflect his true view as a thinker.

Comment: @robev I did not reply to you because I was sick with Covid. I am much better now. Abandoning G-d certainly does mean to deny G-d. Why would you think otherwise? Unless you want to reject the plain meaning of the midrash?  "If only Me they would abandon..." does not translate as deny - it means deny. If one abandons G-d, then this means that one denies G-d.

Comment: @TamirEvan I do not know what you mean by "idolatrous Jews". If what you mean by this is a Jew who worships other gods, why would such a Jew be considered a good Jew and an atheist would not? Such distinctions in the midrash is nothing other than rationalization. The plain meaning of the midrash is that one who abandons G-d (atheism or idolatry) is nonetheless a good Jew, and not a heretic, by virtue of observing Torah.

Comment: @TamirEvan Abandoning G-d certainly does mean to deny G-d. This  is nothing more than rationalization to argue that abandon does not mean to deny. It means deny.

Comment: -1 The answer does not cite it's source for the quote it attributes to G-d, nor does it explain how it concludes that "_an atheist Jew who keeps Torah is a Jew in good standing in the eyes of G-d_", from the quote. If Eicha Rabbah Petichta 2 is it's source, then the quote is also a mistranslation of truncated quote of a Midrash that says nothing about atheists, and (the Midrash) is based on a verse that is talking about people having committed idolatry.